# Send email on new bug in Mantis

Tags: email, configuration, config, mantis

For a particular project, I am trying to configure mantis to send an email to all Supervisors (65) whenever a new bug is submitted.

To do this I have added an entry to the Configuration Report page as so:

```
Username: All Users
Project Name: Test New
Type: Complex
Value:

array ('new' => array('threshold_min' => '65', 'threshold_max' => '65'))
```

When I add that it re-formats it like so:

```
array (
  'new' => 'array(\'threshold_min => \'65',
  'threshold_max' => '65\')',
)
```

and doesn't send the emails to the project supervisors.

Can someone assist me please? Very new to configuring Mantis!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that I also had to make the Supervisor enabled for 'E-mail on Change of Handler' (I also had to do this for Manager level to receive emails when assigned.

Its now working :)

Comment: How did you do it? Can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

Login as administrator in mantis.

Click on Manage Configuration.

Click on Email Notification.

You will get a table which tells when mail should be triggered at various instance of time, select appropriate options.

[Click here to view the documentation of mantis administrative guide](http://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/administration_guide.pdf)

Attached picture is the snapshot for your assistance...

[image]

*Below is just for your mantis functionality enhancement...*

You can also give CHAT option for different levels of users by including

```
$g_main_menu_custom_options = array (
                array( "Chat", REPORTER, 'chat_page.php' )
                );
```

in your config_inc.php.

I've merged **phpchat** application with mantis.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have this configured, but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure to send emails to a particluar user role as "Manager". Then assign all those 65 people this role in the project.

All these people will get mails.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a  [known limitation](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=13298) in the manage config page, which does not properly handle entry of complex types properly.

I actually started working on a fix for this a while ago based on the initial submission from the issue's reporter, but got sidetracked and never got around to finalizing it. You can find the work in progress on my [github branch](https://github.com/dregad/mantisbt/commits/manage-config-dr).

Until then, I'm afraid that your only option would be to enter the required setup directly in config_inc.php.